# WP how to hide the whole content area on click to show full background image?

Tags: jquery, click, hide, program-entry-point, area

Situation:
I am using Wordpress 3.4.2.
The theme loads Jquery.
I am a newbe in Jquery.
I added the WPSupersized background slider with manual navigation tabs.
The content and widget area's are semi transparent and wrapped in the #main div. So you can see 1/2 of the background images.

Question:
How can Jquery hide-on-click the whole #main area to show the full background picture?
All examples on this forum refer to show-hide parts of text behind a button, but I want to hide the whole #main.

Is there anyone who already found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want toggle show and hide, you can use: $('#your_trigger').click(function(){ $('#main').toggle(); }), if only want to hide the #main, you can use $('#your_trigger').click(function(){ $('#main').hide(); }).

Comment: In the head section I entered: <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('#Show_full_BGimage').click(function(){ $('#main').toggle(); })
</script> From an other bar I defined the trigger: <a href="javascript:toggleDiv('#Show_full_BGimage');" style="background-color: #3B3B3B; padding: 5px 10px;">(X)</a> Inspecting the Elements shows: ReferenceError: toggleDiv is not defined (anonymous function). Can you tell me what I did wrong or didnot do? Thanks

Comment: toggleDiv() is not defined, means there is no such function in your code. you should define your trigger as: <span id="Show_full_BGimage">Click Me</span>.